Prove a linear map $\mathcal{N}$ is completely positive if its Choi operator is positive semi-definite
I'm doing exercise 4.4.1 in Quantum information theory by Wilde. The exercise asks to prove that a linear map $\mathcal{N}_{A\to B}$ is completely positive if its Choi operator is a positive semi-definite operator.
By definition, to show that $\mathcal{N}_{A\to B}$ is completely positive semi-definite, we need to show $(id_R\otimes \mathcal{N}_{A\to B})X_{RA}\geq 0$ for any positive semi-definite operator $X_{RA}$, where $R$ is the reference system. By the hint given in the exercise, the positive semi-definite operator $X_{RA}$ can be decomposed by $X_{RA} = \sum_{l}|\psi_l\rangle \langle \psi_l|$.
Again by the hint and Equation (4.202)-(4.205), we can find a linear operator $V_{A\to A}$ such that
$$(I_R \otimes V_{A \to A})|\Gamma\rangle_{RA}=|\psi\rangle$$
where $|\Gamma\rangle_{RA}$ is the maximally entangled state. Then we have
$$(id_R\otimes \mathcal{N}_{A\to B})X_{RA}=(id_R\otimes \mathcal{N}_{A\to B})\sum_{l}(I_R \otimes V^l_{A \to A})|\Gamma\rangle_{RA} \langle \Gamma|_{RA}(I_R \otimes V^{l\dagger}_{A \to A})$$.
It seems like if I can find an argument to exchange the positions of $(id_R\otimes \mathcal{N}_{A\to B})$ and $(I_R \otimes V^l_{A \to A})$, I have the desired result, but this does not hold in general. Is there anything wrong or missing in my proof?

I think you might've misinterpreted the direction the hint is suggesting. You want to show that if $J(\mathcal{N})$ is a positive semidefinite operator, then $\mathcal{N}$ is completely positive. I won't give away too much, but try applying the spectral decomposition to the operator $J(\mathcal{N})$ itself, and see if you can relate it to the Kraus representation and make use of complete positivity theorems there.

@xzkxyz By assuming $J(\mathcal{N})$ is positive semidefinite we can apply the spectral decomposition to it and then construct the matrix $V_l$ as (4.201)-(4.205) in the book. Then we prove $\mathcal{N}(|i\rangle\langle j |)$ can be decomposed in the form of $V_l$ as (4.212). Finally, we apply the linearity of $\mathcal{N}$ and the Choi-Karus theorem to complete the proof. Is this correct?

I feel like this should have already been discussed in the site, but I can't find the post, so here we are.
Let $J(\mathcal N)\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathbb{C}^m\otimes\mathbb{C}^n)$ be the Choice of the quantum map $\mathcal N:\mathrm{Lin}(\mathbb{C}^n)\to\mathrm{Lin}(\mathbb{C}^m)$.

Observe that $J(\mathcal N)=uu^\dagger$ for some vector $u\in \mathbb{C}^m\otimes\mathbb{C}^n$ iff $\mathcal N(X) = AXA^\dagger$ with $u=\operatorname{vec}(A)$.
Observe that $J(\mathcal N)\ge0$ iff there's a set of orthogonal vectors $u_k$ such that $J(\mathcal N)=\sum_k u_k u_k^\dagger$. Or equivalently, there's a set of orthonormal vectors $\tilde u_k$ and positive reals $\lambda_k$ such that $$J(\mathcal N)=\sum_k \lambda_k \tilde u_k\tilde u_k^\dagger.$$
Thus $J(\mathcal N)\ge0$ iff $\mathcal N$ admits a Kraus decomposition, i.e. there's operators $A_k$ such that $$\mathcal N(X)=\sum_k A_k X A_k^\dagger.$$
Observe that a map $\mathcal N$ is completely positive iff it's completely positive on pure states, meaning $(\mathcal N\otimes\operatorname{Id}_p)(\mathbb{P}_\psi)\ge0$ for all pure states $|\psi\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^n\otimes\mathbb{C}^p$ and integers $p$, using the shorthand notation $\mathbb{P}_\psi\equiv|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$.
Observe that a map $\mathcal N$ has a Kraus decomposition iff it has a Steinspring dilation, meaning there's an isometry $V:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^m\otimes \mathbb{C}^q$ such that $\mathcal N(X)=\operatorname{tr}_2[VXV^\dagger]$ for all $X$.
Observe that a map $\mathcal N$ is completely positive iff it has a Kraus decomposition, and thus iff $J(\mathcal N)\ge0$. This is immediate from the Stinespring dilation form, because
$$(\mathcal N\otimes \operatorname{Id}_p)\mathbb{P}_\psi
= \operatorname{tr}_2[\mathbb{P}((V\otimes I)|\psi\rangle)]\ge0,$$
with the RHS clearly positive semidefinite because it's the partial trace applied to the pure state $(V\otimes I)|\psi\rangle$.

You can also skip some of these steps by observing that maps of the form $X\mapsto AXA^\dagger$ are always completely positive, and that sums of completely positive maps are completely positive.
An alternative route is to observe that a map is completely positive iff it's $n$-positive, and that $J(\mathcal N)\ge0$ is the same as saying $\mathcal N$ is $n$-positive.

It seems like the Steps 1-3 have already proved the result by applying the Choi-Kraus theorem. If the mapping can be decomposed as in Step 3 then it must be completely positive?

@hzxscyq I mean sure, it totally depends on which results you assume to be already known. These reasonings assume you don't know other results about complete positivity other than the basic definitions. Or in other words, you can see steps 4-6 as a way to prove maps with Kras decompositions must be CP. But you can absolutely prove it more directly, as I also mentioned in the last paragraphs. I like this approach simply because I find it more explicit and easier to understand intuitively.
